# Slow Motion em Transição de View Pager Android

Tags: android, animação

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação *Android*, cujo uma das funcionalidades exige ter um *ViewPager* de imagens, essas imagens irão ficar transitando de uma para outra automaticamente em um intervalo de tempo que eu definir. Isso já está feito.
O problema é que quando passa de uma imagem para outra, a transição é rápida, queria saber alguma forma de simular a transição de como fosse passando o dedo lentamente sobre a tela. Desde já agradeço.

Animação de Transição de Itens do Pager

```
public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) {
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 0) {

        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);

    } else if (position <= 1) {

        view.setAlpha(1 - position);


        view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);

        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        Log.i("SCALE", String.valueOf(scaleFactor));
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

    } else {
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comportamento Ciclico que faz a transição do ViewPager de Três em Três Segundos

```
public void controlTimeSlidePageAdvert(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mPagerAdverts.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapterAdverts.getCount() - 1)
                        mPagerAdverts.setCurrentItem(0);
                    else
                        mPagerAdverts.setCurrentItem(mPagerAdverts.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
           });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Poste o código que faz essa transição.

Comment: @ramaral , pronto, se souber de algo, agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julgo que isto deve ir de encontro ao que pretende:

```
private final static int PAGER_TRANSITION_DURATION_MS = 500;
private void animatePagerTransition(final boolean forward) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, mPager.getWidth());
    animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            if(mPager.isFakeDragging())
                mPager.endFakeDrag();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            if(mPager.isFakeDragging())
                mPager.endFakeDrag();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });

    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        private int oldDragPosition = 0;

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int dragPosition = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            int dragOffset = dragPosition - oldDragPosition;
            oldDragPosition = dragPosition;
            //Testar isFakeDragging() garante que fakeDragBy()
            //não lança IllegalStateException
            //se a página for movida manualmente durante a animação 
            if(mPager.isFakeDragging()){
                mPager.fakeDragBy(dragOffset * (forward ? -1 : 1));
            }else{
                animation.cancel();
            }
        }
    });

    animator.setDuration(PAGER_TRANSITION_DURATION_MS);
    mPager.beginFakeDrag();
    animator.start();
}
```

<sub>Adaptado desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976741/2556111) no SOen</sub>

Para usá-lo altere o método `controlTimeSlidePageAdvert()` da seguinte forma:

```
public void controlTimeSlidePageAdvert(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    else
                        //mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                        animatePagerTransition(true);
                }
           });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 3000);
}
```

**Notas:**

- `animatePagerTransition(true)` avança uma página.
- `animatePagerTransition(false)` retrocede uma página.
- `PAGER_TRANSITION_DURATION_MS` define o tempo em milissegundos que demora a transição.